# Link Visual C againts MinGW's static library

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mingw, static-libraries

How can one link Visual C++ (2010) console app with a STATIC library created by `MinGW` (`*.a` format)? Is it compatible with Visual C++ 2010?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not compatible.

However, if you extract all the object files from the library (use `ar`), the VC++ linker is able to deal with those (I tested it, although I used cygwin gcc rather than mingw gcc).  Note that you may still have name mangling problems if you don't use `extern "C"`.

You may of course use VC++'s `LIB.EXE` tool to make these into a static library in VC++ format.

---

As @Michael points out, you will definitely have problems if you try to pass non-POD C++ objects between modules built with different compilers.  The fix for this is the same as the DLL case: write a wrapper built with the same compiler (in this case mingw) that exposes a C-compatible interface usable from other toolchains.

---

```
// minimal.cpp
extern "C" int m(void) { return 7; }
```

---

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.0-1/gcc4-4.5.0-1/src/gcc-4.5.0/co
nfigure --srcdir=/gnu/gcc/releases/respins/4.5.0-1/gcc4-4.5.0-1/src/gcc-4.5.0 --
prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --libexecdi
r=/usr/lib --datadir=/usr/share --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --dataroo
tdir=/usr/share --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc4 --datadir=/usr/share --infodir=/usr
/share/info --mandir=/usr/share/man -v --with-gmp=/usr --with-mpfr=/usr --enable
-bootstrap --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable
-static --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --disable-__cxa_atexit --with-gnu
-ld --with-gnu-as --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada
,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-lto --enable-jav
a-awt=gtk --disable-symvers --enable-libjava --program-suffix=-4 --enable-libgom
p --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-threads=posix --with-arch=i686 --with
-tune=generic --enable-libgcj-sublibs CC=gcc-4 CXX=g++-4 CC_FOR_TARGET=gcc-4 CXX
_FOR_TARGET=g++-4 GNATMAKE_FOR_TARGET=gnatmake GNATBIND_FOR_TARGET=gnatbind --wi
th-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.0 (GCC)

$ gcc -c minimal.cpp
```

---

```
// minmain.cpp
extern "C" int m(void);

#include <iostream>

int main(void) { std::cout << m() << "\n"; }
```

---

```
R:\>cl /c /EHsc minmain.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

minmain.cpp

R:\>link minmain.obj minimal.o
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


R:\>minmain
7
```

Comment: The object files will not be compatible either.

Comment: @Michael: They are, I just tested it.

Comment: @Ben: well, shut my mouth!  Thanks for actually testing that.  I'll have to delete my comment...

Comment: @James: I probably shouldn't post this comment in case I'm easily proven wrong again, but one thing to keep in mind is that MinGW is designed to use msvcrt.dll as a runtime, and VS 2010 is designed to use msvcrt100.dll (or a staticly linked version of it). Be aware that in more complex scenarios where runtime functionality is involved you might run into tricky issues.

Comment: @Michael: That's a good point.  I mentioned name mangling, but of course the layout issues are potentially a much bigger problem.  The runtime library is actually less of a problem than code from standard headers that got inlined.  Added a few words to my answer to address this.

Comment: @Michael: Well, I guess, to avoid this issues I will transform my MinGW static library into a shared one (DLL). There won't be any problems, when linking it then in Visual C 2010, right?

Comment: @James: As long as you aren't sharing C++ standard objects (like `std::string` or `std::vector`) between the mingw code and the MSVC code, that should be fine.

Comment: The problem goes beyond just C++ objects. See the section with the heading, "What problems exist if an application uses both msvcrt.dll and msvcr100.dll?" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx  Also see: "Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx

Comment: @Michael: most of those don't apply to use of a static library, which will get linked to `msvcr100.dll`.  If the mingw code is linked into a separate DLL, then it will load a second CRT version, and sharing isn't allowed.