# Intel C/C++ linker using MinGW library

Tags: mingw, static-libraries, icc

Can Intel linker on Windows use a static library compiled by MinGW? Are they binary compatible? On Wikipedia and in one "White paper", they say on Linux yes, but what about Windows and the newest ICC and MinGW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to link MSVC under Pelles C both static and dynamically.

The Intel compiler on windows actually does not provide its own CRT library, instead relying on the MSVC one, i've not tried it but MinGW tool kit SHOULD be binary compatible as long as there's no GCC extensions used in the headers.

I'd suggest you just try it, i'm going to see how fesable it is to do myself(don't want to break VS) and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Intel compiler uses the same format as MSVC, so it would be worth trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781777/link-visual-c-againts-mingws-static-library/6781805#6781805).

However I don't have the Intel compiler so I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to static link, because mingw lib use itself CRT/math wrapper.
You can try to use a dynamic dll instead.

Comment: but MinGW-produced static libraries **can** be linked with MSVC code. If @Ben Boigt is right in another answer, it's a good change that it's possible with ICC too.

Comment: That's right, but not all static lib can be directly linked with MSVC, icc in the same.. We can discuss it further when you came across link stage problems.